# Is it possible to add an overlay of cities to a map made using choroplethr?

Tags: r, choropleth, choroplethr

I am brand spankin' new when it comes to R. Any help you can give me will be *greatly* appreciated.

I am using the choroplethr package to create maps by ZIP code. I want to add an overlay showing cities (and only cities), but using `reference_map = TRUE` just returns a topographical map with state capitals in additional to making the actual colors harder to differentiate.

Is there a way to append a city overlay onto choroplethr, either with a built-in function of choroplethr that I am overlooking or by combining it with some other package?

My current function is

```
zip_choropleth(myexcel,
           title="Mansfield Geographical Capture by ZCTA",
           num_colors=9,
           state_zoom = c("massachusetts","rhode island","connecticut"), 
           reference_map = TRUE) 
           + scale_fill_brewer(palette="YlOrRd")
```

It returns an image like this:

[image: Bad Topographical Map... D:]

And I want something like this (plus the city overlay!):

[image: Good Zip Map! :D]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible. There are a few things you need to understand in order to accomplish it:

1. All choroplethr functions return ggplot2 objects. The scale for these plots is long and lat.
2. You can add another layer to ggplots with the `+` operator.
3. You need to know the long and lat of all the cities you want to add. According to google, Boston is at long=42.361145, lat=-71.057083.
4. Choroplethr itself has no knowledge of cities and their locations.

Here is demonstration of using `geom_point` to to add a black dot for Boston:

```
library(choroplethrZip)
library(ggplot2)

data(df_pop_zip)

zip_choropleth(df_pop_zip,
               state_zoom = c("massachusetts","rhode island","connecticut")) +
  geom_point(aes(x=-71.057083, y=42.361145), size=5, color="black")
```

[image: choropleth with dot for Boston]

Note: this just adds a dot. You would have to use something else to add the text. Take a look at the ggplot2 help files for `?geom_label` and `?geom_text`.

Comment: Are you the same Ari who created choroplethr? Regardless, I really appreciate the assistance. This worked perfectly!

Comment: Followup question: I am trying to add multiple points at once using `geom_point(lookup, mapping=aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), size=2, color="black")` where `lookup` is a dataframe containing a bunch of latitudes and longitudes, but I am getting an error say "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'group' not found". Is there a way to add points en masse or do I have to add a few hundred unique snippets of code?

Comment: Yes, it's me :)

Comment: Regarding question #2: Each layer can contain its own dataframe. So you can create a new object like `df_cities` that has the coordinates for each city. And then pass it to `geom_point`

Comment: If you have further questions, it is probably best to create a new question

Comment: I will do that then. Thank you again for your time.